# Why does Android BitmapFactory.decodeFile() want 4x the memory needed?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have an 8MB png and when I try to load it into an Android ImageView I get an OutOfMemoryError that says it tried to allocate 32MB of memory and failed.

I'm working on changing the code to downsample the image to avoid using too much memory to avoid most of these problems, so I'm not looking for answers about downsampling. I'm trying to understand why the memory needs of the image are higher than the file size would imply.

Why is Android trying to allocate 4x the memory when loading the png?

I've set my options to tell it not to scale for pixel density:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inScaled = false;
```

Comment: Do you really mean an 8MB PNG, as stored in a file? PNG is a compressed image format; an 8MB PNG would be absolutely massive. What is the image resolution?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, an 8MB png stored as a file. It is 2848 x 4209 pixels. We have png files much larger (25 MB or more with 4032 × 5169 pixels) and we are using downsampling to load smaller images from disk, but without downsampling the system was throwing OOM errors when loading images as small as a 3 MB png file at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is 2848 x 4209 pixels

At the 4 bytes/pixel rate for `ARGB_8888`, that will be 47,948,928 bytes as a `Bitmap`.

The on-disk size of images represents a red herring. The major file formats (particularly PNG and JPEG) are compressed as files. That does not matter. What matters is the resolution and bit depth of the desired decoded image.

Also note that your image is bigger than the display resolution of most Android devices. Depending on your use case, you may wish to consider widgets like [this one](https://github.com/tibbi/subsampling-scale-image-view) that can load and display portions of the image at a time.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And thank you for the pointer to the downsampling/tiling widget. I didn't want to have to write something like that myself and had been considering less optimal solutions.